# Regex pattern for repeated words

Tags: java, regex

I am very new to regex, I am learning it now. I have a requirement like this:

Any String starts with #newline# and also ends with #newline#. In between these two words, there could be (0 or more spaces) or (0 or more #newline#).

below is an example:

```
#newline#  #newline# #newline##newline# #newline##newline##newline#.
```

How to do regex for this?

I have tried this, but not working

```
^#newline#|(\s+#newline#)|#newline#|#newline#$
```

Comment: Your example string ends with `#newline`, not `#newline#`. If it is a typo, use  [`^#newline#(?:\s*#newline#)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/mI9nD2/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `^#newline#|(\s+#newline#)|#newline#|#newline#$` matches either a `#newline#` at the start of the string (`^#newline#`), or 1+ whitespaces followed with `#newline#` (`(\s+#newline#)`), or `#newline#`, or  (and this never matches as the previous catches all the cases of `#newline#`) a `#newline#` at the end of the string (`#newline#$`).

You may match these strings with

```
^#newline#(?:\s*#newline#)*$
```

or (if there should be at least 2 occurrences of  `#newline#` in the string)

```
^#newline#(?:\s*#newline#)+$
                          ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mI9nD2/1).

- `^` - start of string
- `#newline#`  - literal string
- `(?:\s*#newline#)*`  - zero (**NOTE**: replacing `*` with `+` will require at least 1) or more sequences of

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `#newline#`  - a literal substring
- `$` - end of string.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/KOsOvD):

```
String s = "#newline#  #newline# #newline##newline# #newline##newline##newline#";
System.out.println(s.matches("#newline#(?:\\s*#newline#)+"));
// => true
```

Note: inside `matches()`, the expression is already anchored, and `^` and `$` can be removed.

Comment: I understand the *Any String starts with #newline# and also ends with #newline#* requirement so that a `#newline#` string should match (a single `#newline#` is both at the start and at the end of the string). Otherwise, one more `#newline#` must be at the end before `$`.

Comment: ...or last `*` could be replaced with `+`

Comment: Ah, yes, I am so busy now, I overlooked that :)

Comment: Working like a charm..Thank you

Comment: Updated the Java demo: `String#matches()` already anchors the regex, so it can be shortened a bit inside it to make up for the double backslashes with `\s`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand the requirements, it should be this:

```
^#newline#(\s|#newline#)*#newline#$
```

this will not match your example string, since it does not start with #newline#

without the ^ and the $ it matches a sub-string.

Check out http://www.regexplanet.com/ to play around with Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the pattern and matches classes to identify.
You can give the patternString string at runtime
patternString="newline";

```
public void findtheMatch(String patternString)
{
     String text    ="#newline#  #newline# #newline##newline# #newline##newline##newline# ";

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

            while(matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group(1));
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well:

`#newline#[\s\S]+#newline#`

It says, match anything that starts with `#newline#` followed by any combination of  whitespace or non-whitespace characters and ends with `#newline#`.